# How to transfer field names to groups in a React json schema ui: groups nested object scenario

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsonschema

How to transfer field names to groups in a React json schema ui: groups nested object scenario. For example: object1.field1

I want to group the modelMetada and legancyMetaData objects given in the schema by selecting them from the properties inside.

The reason I want this is to show it by grouping it as I want in the tab.

```
    const newSchema = {
  $schema: 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
  title: 'Physical Model',
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    modelMetadata: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        name: {
          type: 'string',
          title: 'Model Name',
          description: 'Name of the Model',
        },
        displayName: {
          type: 'string',
          title: 'Model Display Name',
          description: 'Display Name of the Model',
        },
      },
    },
    legacyMetaData: {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        id: {
          type: 'string',
          title: 'Legacy ID',
          description: 'ID of the Model in the Legacy System',
        },
        name: {
          type: 'string',
          title: 'Legacy Name',
          description: 'Legacy Name of the Model',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

 const groups = [
{
  modelMetadata: ['modelMetadata'],
  legacyMetaData: ['legacyMetaData'],
  customize: ['modelMetadata.displayName','legacyMetaData.name'], // ????
},
```

];

The code block I grouped

```js
const doGrouping = ({ properties, groups, formContext }):any => {
  const mapped = groups.map((g) => {
    if (typeof g === 'string') {
      const found = properties.filter((p) => p.name === g);
      if (found.length === 1) {
        const el = found[0];
        return el.content;
      }
      return EXTRANEOUS;
    } else if (typeof g === 'object') {
      const { templates } = formContext;
      const GroupComponent = templates
        ? templates[g['ui:template']]
        : DefaultTemplate;
      // @ts-ignore
      const tempProperties = Object.keys(g).reduce((acc, key) => {
        const field = g[key];
        if (key.startsWith('ui:')) return acc;
        if (!Array.isArray(field)) return acc;
        return [
          ...acc,
          {
            name: key,
            children: doGrouping({
              properties,
              formContext,
              groups: field,
            }),
          },
        ];
      }, []);
      return <GroupComponent properties={tempProperties} />;
    }
    throw new Error(`Invalid object type: ${typeof g} ${g}`);
  });
  const remainder = mapped.filter((m) => m === REST);
  if (remainder.length > 0) {
    throw new Error('Remainder fields not supported');
  }
  return mapped;
};
```

Comment: where you want to transfer? Add full code

Comment: I've added the complete code.

Comment: @Shubham Verma I've added the complete code

Comment: what i understand from your question. You want to render tab component based on the groups for ex: if it is `modelMetadata ` then find all `modelMetadata ` from `newSchema` and similar for another things right?

Comment: Let me explain my scenario;I have a schema like that
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "a": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "title1",
      "properties": {
        "a1": "a1",
        "a2": "a2"
      }
    },
    "b": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "title2",
      "properties": {
        "b1": "b1",
        "b2": "b2"
      }
    }
  }
}
 and I can seperate that schema into two groups as "a" and "b" in tabs . But i want to make other group only including a1 and b1 but not adding to schema. and display them in my added tab. How can i do it ?

Comment: I missed this yesterday. I am still not sure what exactly you want. I tried this small [poc](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-leftpad-njxrt). Does this fix your problem?

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I wanted. You gave the data as an object of your own design. But I have to use json schema. There is an example here at the [poc](https://codesandbox.io/s/tabbed-mozilla-form-vmsqf?file=/src/index.js). I want to adapt the example in  [poc](https://codesandbox.io/s/tabbed-mozilla-form-vmsqf?file=/src/index.js) to my problem.